# GNU GetText and Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Is there an implementation or tutorial about GNU GetText for Xamarin Android?
Using GetText tools for localization seems to me more powerful than other solutions but I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this version which support Mono and dotnet core. https://github.com/neris/NGettext